# Autocomplete in Kendo UI MVC Scheduler Editor Template not working

Tags: kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I added a autocomplete in the scheduler editor template. It returns the correct data when I input the first char in the textbox, but after that, read action is not called anymore (it won't reach the break point in controller) and it seems the autocomplete cached the results from the first char input.

For example, in the database, I have 2000 client names. Among them 100 whose name starts with 'a'. When the editor launched from scheduler, I input 'a', it shows 100 names. Then, I delete the 'a', input 'c'. Nothing shows up, but I have 200 names starts with 'c'. And this time, it did not hit the breakpoint in the controller.

Here is the autocomplete in editor template:

```
<div data-container-for="client" class="k-edit-field">
 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("client")
    .DataTextField("ClientName")        
    .Placeholder("Please fill in Name")     
    .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetClientList", "Scheduler").Data("onAdditionalClientData");
            });
        })      
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100%" })     
    .MinLength(1)       
    .Height(300)
    )
</div>
```

The scheduler is in index.cshtml, I put the javascript in index.cshtml. If I put it in the template file, it shows error.

```
<script>
    function onAdditionalClientData() {
        return {
            query: $("#client").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

In the controller, I have

```
public JsonResult GetClientList(string query)
{
    ....
    var ret = doctors.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Take(20).ToList();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I searched, it seems we can use autocomplete in the scheduler edit template. But all sample code I can find is for Kendo UI and loads data from static list. I need to load the data from the database using Json call.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oh, well, figured it out.

```
source.Read(read =>
{
    read.Action("GetClientList", "Scheduler").Data("onAdditionalClientData");
}).ServerFiltering(true);
```

The only change needs is to add ServerFiltering(true). otherwise, it will do the Read action once and use Client side filtering, which is exactly what I saw.

Maybe Kendo can improve the doc for UI for MVC a little.